# Calling setIdentity in SFMCSdkReadyListener crashes with UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I can share more information if needed. At the moment, I don't know what I need to share.

The Library version is 8.0.4

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property identity has not been initialized
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.SFMCSdk.setIdentity(SFMCSdk.kt:306)
       at de.is24.mobile.push.salesforce.SalesForcePushSdk$updateAttributes$1.invoke(SalesForcePushSdk.kt:357)
       at de.is24.mobile.push.salesforce.SalesForcePushSdk$updateAttributes$1.invoke(SalesForcePushSdk.kt:346)
       at de.is24.mobile.push.salesforce.SalesForcePushSdk$sam$com_salesforce_marketingcloud_sfmcsdk_SFMCSdkReadyListener$0.ready(SalesForcePushSdk.kt)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.WhenReadyHandler.execute(WhenReadyHandler.kt:14)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.WhenReadyHandler.deliverSdk$lambda-0(WhenReadyHandler.kt:10)
       at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.WhenReadyHandler.$r8$lambda$Emdr_HlwEfReRvUS2Z71HTw6sJI(WhenReadyHandler.kt)
       at androidx.room.QueryInterceptorDatabase$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$9425620339d5d757f34a17c8174fab1a30b5d96472d3b17935abade4529be7c3$0.run$bridge(QueryInterceptorDatabase.java:4)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set a value for either PUSH or CDP in your config.  Please see docs https://bit.ly/3fApTUp

Comment: We followed the documentation for the setup. We set push config. is configure method async because we set some of the attributes after the configuration call.

Comment: Show me how you're doing all this, but please sanitize your application's values: appId, etc.  The _only_ way that we have been able to reproduce this is to init the SDK without populating pushModuleConfig.